# Can Youtube's embeddable iframe be modify?

Tags: iframe, youtube, lazy-loading

I tested lazy loading youtube videos on my site and the page speed improves by 3 seconds. I load a javascript and changed the src attribute for a data-src one.

Ex:

```
<iframe data-src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VID" height="360" width="550"></iframe>
```

But I don't know if the iframe code can be modified and if this goes against Youtubes' terms and conditions: https://www.youtube.com/t/terms.

Comment: I can't see why this would be a problem. But if you're worried about it, why not lazily add their unmodified iframe code to the page?

Comment: @OllyHodgson, I tried that but I had to add more JavaScript. [Lazy Load XT](https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt/#iframe-embedded-videos-youtube-vimeo-etc) is the one I have for images and it works for iframes too. I'm trying to introduce the less modifications I can.